# Executing methods one after another with pauses between executing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, method-call

Newbie obj-c question.
I am writing a simple iPad presentation not for Appstore. My task is to implement few methods executed one after another with little pauses between them. Main structure looks like this:

- view loads
- two seconds pause, then executing method1
- two seconds pause, then executing method2
- two seconds pause, then executing method3
  etc...

First method I am calling from -viewDidLoad:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(firstCountStarts) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Everything is ok here, method starts 2 seconds after view loads.
From inside method1 I try to call method 2 in the same way but it start to execute simultaneously with method1. Same way triggered method3 (called from method2) and all methods after them not executed at all. I tried to situate all this methods in -ViewDidLoad and to call them with delays:

```
 [self method1];
 [self performSelector:@selector(method2) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
 [self performSelector:@selector(method3) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];
 etc...
```

But after method2 is calling all methods after didn't executed. If I understand right the issue in threads. Do I need to use GCD to execute methods in different queues? Or maybe problem in else?

Thanks, colleagues!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add these to an NSOperation queue...

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

[queue  addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self method1];
}];

[queue  addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
    [self method2];
}];

[queue  addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
    [self method3];
}];

...
```

This will then run each one only after the previous one has finished and put the 2 second delay in for you.

Careful about using this to do an UI stuff though. This will run in a Background thread so you may need to deal with that.

Maybe this might work better you could do it by subclassing NSOperation but that's a lot of work for not much benefit.

Run this from where ever you want, I suggest putting all this into a function called setUpQueue or something.

Then from viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad or somewhere else, on a button press, etc... do...

```
[self setUpQueue];
```

All you have to do is add stuff to the queue, the queue will then manage itself.

Comment: I just tried this code here as I could use something like this in my project. But for some reason, the selectors inside the blocks are not called. Is there any reason why they wouldn't work? Works fine if I just call the method itself, but inside the selector method is never called

Comment: Ah, just thought, the performSelectorWithDelay will bump it off onto another thread.  Could try something else...

Comment: NSTimer instead of performSelectorWithDelay?

Comment: Inside the blocks you can't use anything that will push the thread off to a BG thread as that will complete the operation.  Each operation has to run synchronously.  You can't use NSTimer or performSelectorWithDelay etc...

Comment: Ok, but how to implement pauses this way?

Comment: It isn't very elegant but you could use +[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] this should work.

Comment: In every block I need to write [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];  ?

Comment: And one more question: I need to call this blocks from anywhere or they are executed without calling, just by itselves?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the single timer and write a switch statement around the methods you want to execute in the order you want to execute them. e.g.

```
int turn = 0;
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(runmethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

then in run method

```
switch(turn)
{
  case 0:
        // do method 1 stuff
        ++turn;
        break;
  case 1:
        // do method 2 stuff
        ++turn;
        break;
    .
    .
    .
}

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(runmethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```