# How to run two methods in sequence at time delay?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

```
[self goToStage:currentStage];
[actor deathAnimation];
```

I have these two methods. I want to call it one by one in sequence. When one is completed after second one is started.

```
//this method used in nsobject subclass
-(void)deathAnimation {

    //Play death animation

}

//this method in cclayer subclass
-(void)goToStage:(int)stage {

   //changing scene
}
```

IN my tick function at particular event i want to call in seqeuence

I use following code but it not working

```
[CCSequence actions:[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:actor selector:@selector(deathAnimation)], [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:4.0], [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(goToStage:)], nil];

Now what i do? Please tell me.. Is there something wrong?
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375846/executing-methods-one-after-another-with-pauses-between-executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CCDelayTime, that is used to give a delay, and CCCallBlock,to pass a method to be invoked, like this:

```
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1],
                                    [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{[self goToStage:currentStage];}],
                                    [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1],
                                    [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{[actor deathAnimation}], nil]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a block in you inteface as e.g.

```
typedef void(^MyCompletion)(void);
```

edit you `deathAnimation` to take a block parameter as

```
- (void)deathAnimationWithCompletion:(MyCompletion)finish {
    //..death animation
    //...

    //when animation finishes
    finish(); // This will call your completion block
}
```

Call this method as

```
[self deathAnimationWithCompletion:^{
    [self goToStage:2];
}];
```

You can read up on blocks at [Ray Wenderlichs fantastic blog.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9328/creating-a-diner-app-using-blocks-part-1)

Hope it helps!

**EDIT DUE TO COMMENT**
In cocos2d I think you can also make a sequence like this

```
id aFuncCall = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(deathAnimation)];
id antoherFuncCall = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(goToSecondStange:)];
CCSequence *sequence = [CCSequence actions:aFuncCall,anotherFuncCall, nil];
[self runAction:sequence];
```

But my cocos2d programming skills are bit outdated so not sure if this works...

Comment: deathAnimation & goToSecondStange both of type is void type. so in ccsequence, you don't use method directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can call

[actor deathAnimation];

at the end of the goToStage function, that way it will execute everything in goToStage before calling deathAnimation.

You could put a delay timer in the goToStage if you require it to wait for a specific amount of time.

Comment: no no...i want to callling deathAnimation before calling goToStage

Comment: ok sorry I misread what you were after. You can then call [self goToStage:] at the end of the [actor deathAnimation] function as Filip suggested